# Reaching end of function without return statement

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

ANSI X3.159-1989, section 3.6.6.4, lines 33-35 state:

> “If a return statement without an expression is executed, and the
>   value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is
>   undefined.  Reaching the } that terminates a function is equivalent to
>   executing a return statement without an expression.”

I've been looking through `ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E)`, `ISO/IEC 9899:2011(E)`, `ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)`, and `ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E)` for similar statements, especially the 2nd sentence, but about all I've found pertains to function main. If someone could point me to the correct spot(s) in any one of these documents (I don't care which) I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the first sentence (your source appears to be wrong or outdated):

> #### C 2011 6.8.6.4 The return statement
>
> **1** A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

As to the second sentence:

> #### C 2011 6.9.1 Function definitions
>
> **12** If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

In both C99 TC2 and C11 it is 6.9.1/12:

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

In C++11 and C++14 it is [stmt.return]/2:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function