# Why different values inside called function and inside calling function?

Tags: c

The values which are output from inside the called function and from inside the calling function are not identical.

Why are values of `y` and value of `m` not the same?

[screenshot of code and output, showing "Value of m 6" and "value of y 13"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5hdT.jpg)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int pass(a);
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("Hello world\n");
    printf("Enter the x  ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    y = pass(x);

    printf("value of y  %d",y);
    return 9;
    }
pass(m)
{
    m = m + 5;
    printf("Value of m %d\n",m);
    // return 5;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
Enter the x  1
Value of m 6
value of y 13
```

Comment: you're not returning anything from function `pass` is it intentional?

Comment: `m` is a local variable within `pass()` and is destroyed when `pass()` returns. Since you don't `return m;` and you don't pass the address of `m`, e.g. `int pass (int *m)`) the modified value of `m` is never seen back in the caller. Either `int pass (int m) { ... return m; }` or `void pass (int *m) { *m = *m + 5 };` and call `pass (&x); y = x;` or you wont see the change in `main()`. Best of both worlds `int pass (int *m) { *m = *m + 5; return *m; }` and have the option of calling `pass (&x); y = x;` or `y = pass (&x);`

Comment: What values do you observe? Maybe the number of characters in "Value of 42\n" ? 42 being an example of a two-digit result of "input +5". Please report the values you observe for inputs like 5, 7, 10, 95, , 97, 100...

Comment: What machine are you on that this didn't give an error at line 2? I think that's an error in all versions of C.

Comment: @Neil Ancient compilers did a lot of guessing. Current compilers still do, usually you can get them to complain as warnings, which would be a good idea.

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried compiling it with C89 GCC (implicit int), and it still says "a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition".

Comment: It could be a copy-paste error by OP, or they have a more tolerant compiler, like https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#

Comment: For the OP, the easiest way to fix this is to re-order your functions, then you don't need to prototype, `static int pass(int m) {... return m;} int main(void) {... [return 0;*]}` (*not necessary except in C89).

Comment: Thank you all for the effort , now I got about "return" function

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, this should not even attempted to be explained, because of undefined behaviour, compare [Reaching end of function without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339768/reaching-end-of-function-without-return-statement)
but ...

Assuming that my guess on the pattern of returned values (a constant plus the number of digits in "input + 5") is correct:

By chance, the default assumptions of the compiler when seeing the incomplete prototype `int pass(a);` (should be `int pass(int a);`), allow it to associate the later provided implementation of `pass(m)` (should be `int pass(int m);`, or  more consistently `int pass(int a)`).

So when you call `y = pass(x);`, `y` gets the value returned by that implementation.

The implementation then lacks a clean `return` statement (it has one, but inactive by being a comment).
So at the end of executing that function, the most recently determined result is returned, another default of compilers which you should better not rely on for clarity and readability of code.

The most recent result is the return value of the call to `printf()`.
That return value is the number of successfully printed characters.
You might want to read up on `printf()` and its return value in its specification, and about the concept of return values, prototypes and data types of parameters and return values in general.

For the output you show in your picture of text,
`Value of m 6\n` (thanks for making me type that...) that is, let me count
`^   ^    ^  ^`
`1   5   10  13`,
13, including the newline at the end of the output from inside the function.

Obviously, this is completely unrelated to the value of the local variable `m`, which is seen in the picture of text.

For more details on how to achieve what you might try to do see the comment David C. Rankin.

Comment: Really thank you so much for your effort now I can understand better than before .